# Cortana can't connect to Internet in Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, cortana

I'm having some trouble with Cortana.  Starting this morning (it was working great until then), I can't get Cortana to do nearly anything because she can't connect to the Internet.  I don't think I've changed any settings that would cause this.  Can anybody out there give me some insight on why this is happening and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you verified the internet connection is on and you can surf the internet when using a web-browser? Are you getting any error messages?

Comment: Yes, Internet connection works fine except on Cortana.  The only thing I get from her is stuff like "the Internet and I aren't talking right now," and other generic messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I figured it out.  I had to go into my account settings and log in with a local account instead of my microsoft account.  After doing this, Cortana works exactly as intended and all is smooth sailing.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and found that Cortana and the internet would start "talking" again by closing her process (SearchUI.exe). After a moment, the process will restart and she should be fine...for now. This is not a permanent solution as the issue occasionally happens again. Hope this helps.

Comment: Interesting.  That process doesn't start for me, and when I attempt to manually start it, it closes itself after just a short moment.  That could very well be what's causing the problem with Cortana, but now I need to know what's causing the problem with SearchUI!